Is it possible to retrieve a string from the source code of a Go binary?
Let's say I make a go program where in the source code I create a string variable with a hard-coded value that contains an API token, then I build the program, transfer it to another remote machine, then run the binary on that machine.
Is it possible to retrieve the API token from the binary content ? or even from inspecting the process at runtime ?
Let's use this modern basic example with standard Go tools:
import "golang.org/x/oauth2"

//[...]

  ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&oauth2.Token{AccessToken: "<my_API_token>"})
  client := NewClient(oauth2.NoContext, ts)

Can this code leak the token from its resulting compiled binary ?

Since the string somehow has to be used by the program it somehow needs to be stored in the program. So of course it can be retrieved by analyzing the compiled binary or the running process.

slightly off-topic: youtube channel "low level learning" is a good source for becoming aware of what is very wrong to do. The tool to dump strings from an executable comes by pretty often, as well as disassemblers.

Yes. Type strings <program> and that will in most cases be enough to spit it out.
